# Run progress bar until being logged in, because sometimes internet speed is slow and some times it is fast. (C#, Windows Form Application)

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I am developing a Desktop Application using visual studio(C#, Windows Form Application). Login/Logout and CRUD operations are being performed by API due to which operations are being processed little bit slowly. I wanted to run/show a progress bar until user is being logged in as well as any CRUD operation is being processed.

**Question:** How can I show a progress bar while the user is being logged in?

Your Cooperation will be highly APPRECIATED!

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Have you done any research on this? Here's a good entry point - https://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar

Comment: @PatrickHofman 
How can I the progress bar until user is being logged in?

Comment: Even if you knew how, why would you want to, a progress bar is only meaningful if there is a way of quantifying the progress made, whereas here you're just waiting some arbitrary unknown time until logged in. A spinner or similar would make more sense. (note this doesnt apply to the operations as you can determine progress through said operations if there are multiple)

Comment: Yes, I will prefer "A spinner or similar would make more sense."

Comment: Check my updated answer for "A spinner or similar would make more sense."

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await TimeConsumingOperation();
    }

    public async Task TimeConsumingOperation()
    {
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you are down voting this?